# Copying particular block of xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an xml as below.

```
   <emp>
      <Name>Rice</Name>
      <Designation>Operator</Designation>
      <sal>$2000</sal> 
      <hobbies><description>1.Playaing Games 2.Watching Movies</description></hobbies>
   </emp>
   <emp>
      <Name>Jeff</Name>
      <Designation>Admin</Designation>
      <sal>$1000</sal> 
      <hobbies><description>1.Listening Music</description></hobbies>
   </emp>
```

My requirment whenever the tag `<hobbies>` is encountered i need to copy the hobbies section`(<hobbies>1.Playaing Games 2.Watching Movies</hobbies>)` as it is in the resultant document.
I am using xsl to convert from one xml to other xml.My out should looks like below.

```
 <EmployeeDetails>
    Rice,Operator,$2000
    <hobbies><description>1.Playaing Games 2.Watching Movies</description></hobbies>
  </EmployeeDetails>
   <EmployeeDetails>
    Jeff,Admin,$1000
    <hobbies><description>1.Listening Music</description></hobbies> 
  </EmployeeDetails>
```

Please provide me some pointer to acheive the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use this template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="emp">
        <EmployeeDetails>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(Name, ',', Designation, ',', sal)"/>

            <xsl:copy-of select="hobbies"/>
        </EmployeeDetails>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<EmployeeDetails>
    Rice,Operator,$2000<hobbies>
        <description>1.Playaing Games 2.Watching Movies</description>
    </hobbies>
</EmployeeDetails>
<EmployeeDetails>
    Jeff,Admin,$1000<hobbies>
        <description>1.Listening Music</description>
    </hobbies>
</EmployeeDetails>
```